# Python OSError: [Errno 2]

Tags: python, subprocess

I have the following code that is attempting to start each of the "commands" below in Linux. The module attempts to keep each of the 2 commands running if either should crash for whatever reason.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

commands = [ ["screen -dmS RealmD top"], ["screen -DmS RealmD top -d 5"] ]
programs = [ subprocess.Popen(c) for c in commands ]
while True:
    for i in range(len(programs)):
        if programs[i].returncode is None:
            continue # still running
        else:
            # restart this one
            programs[i]= subprocess.Popen(commands[i])
        time.sleep(1.0)
```

Upon executing the code the following exception is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./marp.py", line 82, in <module>
    programs = [ subprocess.Popen(c) for c in commands ]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 595, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1092, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I think I'm missing something obvious, can anyone see what's wrong with the code above?

Comment: you should use `programs[i].poll()` instead of `programs[i].returncode`.

Comment: related: [subprocess.call using string vs using list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15109665/4279)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use `["screen", "-dmS", "RealmD", "top"]` instead of `["screen -dmS RealmD top"]`.

Maybe also use the complete path to `screen`.

Comment: Docs say a string or a sequence can be used.

Comment: commands = [ ["screen", "-dmS", "RealmD", "top"], ["screen", "-DmS", "RealmD", "top", "-d", "5"] ]

Worked perfectly!

Comment: @colin: In this case a sequence was used and it needs to contain the parameters separately. Probably a simple string (without the []) would also work.

Comment: Either 1 string, or 1 parameter "word" per element of a list.  If you pass a sequence, you should have done the exact parsing that a shell normally does.  If you pass a single string it's parsed exactly the way the shell would have parsed it.

Comment: @umpirsky: from the docs: *"On Unix, if `args` is a string, the string is interpreted as the name or path of the program to execute. However, this can only be done _if not passing arguments to the program_."*

Comment: How do i use `&` sign? Something like this :- `cmd_list=['dd','if=/dev/zero','of=/dev/null','&']`

Answer (score 9):

Only guess is that it can't find `screen`.  Try `/usr/bin/screen` or whatever `which screen` gives you.

Comment: Yep, this was my issue. Command was not in system path as expected.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that your command should be split. subprocces requires that the cmd is a list, not a string.
It shouldn't be:

```
subprocess.call('''awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t";OFS="\n"} {a[$1]=a [$1] OFS $2 FS $3 FS $4} END
{for (i in a) {print i a[i]}}' 2_lcsorted.txt > 2_locus_2.txt''')
```

That won't work. If you feed subprocess a string, it assumes that that is the path to the command you want to execute. The command needs to be a list. Check out http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/724330. Also, because you're using file redirection, you should use `subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)`. You can also use `shlex`.

Comment: `subprocess.call("executable -parameter 1 -hello", shell=True)` works (assuming it is in the PATH of the shell)

Comment: It depends on the call. If you do not parse input then it is as safe as a shell command.

Answer (score 3):

I got same error when i wrote like this :-

```
subprocess.Popen("ls" ,shell = False , stdout = subprocess.PIPE ,stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
```

And problem is solved when i made **shell=True** .It will work

`subprocess.Popen("ls" ,shell = False , stdout = subprocess.PIPE ,stderr = subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)`

Answer (score 2):

```
commands = [ "screen -dmS RealmD top", "screen -DmS RealmD top -d 5" ]
programs = [ subprocess.Popen(c.split()) for c in commands ]
```

Comment: Use `shlex.split()` instead of `string.split()`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case.. I also got stuck with this error and the issue was that my files were in DOS instead of UNIX so at :

```
 return subprocess.call(lst_exp)
```

where lst_exp is a list of args, one of them was "not found" because it was in DOS instead of UNIX but error thrown was the same :

```
File "/var/www/run_verifier.py", line 59, in main
return subprocess.call(lst_exp)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```