# Python - Calling popen with many arguments

Tags: python, exec, popen

I'm attempting to call popen with a list of arguments.

```
    execString = "java -jar {} {} {} {} {} {}".format(os.path.join(config.java_root,
                                                                   config.java_jar),
                                               self.canvasSize,
                                               self.flightId,
                                               self.domain,
                                               self.defPath,
                                               self.harPath)
    execStringList = execString.split()
    print execStringList
    subprocess.Popen([execStringList])
```

execStringList is:

```
['java', '-jar', '/Users/me/Projects/reporting-test/build/clickunit-0.1.jar', '300x1050', '123', 'dev.me.net', '/Users/me/Projects/reporting-test/src/definitions/300x1050.yml', '/Users/me/Projects/reporting-test/out/01/15112']
```

Which according to: [Python OSError: [Errno 2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901982/python-oserror-errno-2) is the correct format. However, I get the following error:

```
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1202, in _execute_child
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

If I treat the execString as a string, I get a different error:

```
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1202, in _execute_child
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Even though if I run this command from terminal, it works.

```
$> java -jar /Users/me/Projects/reporting-test/build/clickunit-0.1.jar 300x1050 123 dev.me.net /Users/me/Projects/reporting-test/src/definitions/300x1050.yml /Users/me/Projects/reporting-test/out/01/3727
```

TIA for the help!

**EDIT**

EDIT EDIT

NEVERMIND, I see the issue. []...thanks! heheh

Comment: I've made the same error! (10 minutes saved from thanks to this question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`execStringList` is already a list, so you can pass it directly to `subprocess.Popen`.

```
execString = "java -jar {} {} {} {} {} {}".format(os.path.join(config.java_root,
                                                               config.java_jar),
                                           self.canvasSize,
                                           self.flightId,
                                           self.domain,
                                           self.defPath,
                                           self.harPath)
execStringList = execString.split()
print execStringList
# Pass execStringList directly to Popen
subprocess.Popen(execStringList)
```

Comment: As a side note, there's really no advantage to putting this whole thing into a string and then splitting it as far as I can see ...