# command line arguments with subprocess.Popen

Tags: python

I've GUI where if i press a button "process" calls a python script which needs one command line argument. so i used subprocess.Popen like this:

```
subprocess.Popen(['chbif /home/vnandak/Work/VS30_Cradle/SV000_sv000/cradle_vs30_dkaplus01_fwd_dl140606_fem140704_v00_mod1.bif'],shell=True)
```

chbif is the alias for the .py script

This works fine but now i want to choose a file of my choice by browsing using askfilename() func from tkFileDailog() module. how can i do this?

I thought of doing it like this:

```
def bifcall():
        name13= askopenfilename()
        subprocess.Popen(['chbif', name13],shell=True)
```

But if i use this it throws an error saying that it does'nt have one more command line argument which is the file name

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Usage: query_master_model filename.bif Note: 1. full path+filename should be specified. 2. [arg] means argument "arg" is optional. Rene Visser, Jan-2007 Last modified: Mar-2010 (using script: /nfzcae/all/femdb/tools/nvh/python/lib/analysis_manager/query_master_model.pyc) this is the error i get

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args) File "/net/s019fc000110ge/mnt_home/vol/home6/vnandak/Python_scripts/remodelstage.py", line 290, in checkbif
    subprocess.Popen(['chbif' + extrafunc.name13],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,shell=False)
  File "/usr/local/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/local/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass `shell=True`, the first argument should be a string, and it will be interpreted as the shell would interpret it. If `shell=False`, then the first argument should be a list, which sort of bypasses the shell.

Here's an answer to another question that explains it well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15109975/451201

Comment: so if i use shell =False it should work tat's wat u say @ jnrbsn then i'll try that

Comment: @ayaan It is customary to accept the best answer (in your opinion) by clicking the checkmark next to that answer when your problem has been solved.

Comment: yeah sry i'll do that but still i get a trace back error that's what i'm figuring out

Comment: @ayaan: If `shell=False`, it should be a list—but a list with each argument in its own string, not a list with one giant string in it. As it is, you're asking it to find a program named `'chbif /home/vnandak/Work/VS3…'` somewhere on the path, and run it with no arguments, which is obviously going to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Because if you use shell=True, you can only use one string as the first argument.

Try to change

```
subprocess.Popen(['chbif', name13],shell=True)
```

to

```
subprocess.Popen('chbif ' + name13,shell=True)
```

But it is not recommended to use shell=True for security reasons (See https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments for details).

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/net/s019fc000110ge/mnt_home/vol/home6/vnandak/Python_scripts/remodelstage.py", line 290, in checkbif
    subprocess.Popen(['chbif' + extrafunc.name13],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,shell=False)
  File "/usr/local/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/local/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception

Comment: the above error trace back error is occuring when i chose the file @Rikka

Comment: @ayaan In the callback, you are using shell=False and a string as the first argument in you Popen function, different from my code. BTW, if you want to use shell=True, you have to add a space after chbif to separate the executable and the arguments ('chbif  ' + name13, shell=True). To make it clear, In Popen(), if you use shell=False, then you need a list as the 1st argument; if you use shell=False, then you need a string as the 1st argument.

Comment: thankq very much for all it's working finally and i understood the concept very well @Rikka

Comment: I would highly recommend using `shell=False` and then passing a list. It's more secure, because you don't have to worry about quoting the filename. Otherwise, you should use something like `pipes.quote` to prevent someone from trying something bad.

Comment: I totally agree with you @jnrbsn .And ayaan , you can use shlex.split() to split you command in order to use the command with shell=False.