# i2c address is out of range

Tags: python, subprocess, i2c

I have been trying to use the MCP23017 along with my beaglebone.. I have however not received my devices yet, but I have started to get my program ready...
I am programming the GPIO pins now.. Here I have tried to read and write the pins using i2c commands as follows:
for write--

```
a=('i2cset', '-y', '0', '0x20', '0x14', '0x01')
subprocess.call(a, shell=True)
```

similarly using i2cget for reading.. However when I try to run it , it give me a notification on my screen saying

```
Usage: i2cset [-f] [-y I2CBUS CHIP-ADDRESS [DATA-ADDRESS [MODE]]
I2CBUS is an integer or an I2C bus name
ADDRESS is an integer (0x03- 0x77)
```

Do I get this notification only because I don't have my device connected yet? Or is it a problem because of using the subprocess module?

Any help is appreciated,

Namita.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you've tried the command in your shell and it worked.
If you set `shell=True` in `subprocess.call()`, it's recommended to use a string instead of a sequence (a tuple in your case) as the first argument.

If you use `shell=True` and pass a sequence as the first argument, the arguments from the second onwards will be treated as the parameters for the shell itself.

Please refer to this answer for more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15109975/870658

You can rewrite as below

```
cmd = 'i2cset -y 0 0x20 0x14 0x01'
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Comment: thank you for that response .. I actually tried that too but I still get the same notification.. Is it because of the unconnected device?

Comment: @NamitaRaju What happens when you run the `i2cset -y 0 0x20 0x14 0x01` in the shell? If it works, then the problem is in `subprocess` module otherwise it's not the problem in Python.

Comment: And when I try it the way you suggested I get a error saying i2cset-y00x200x0A0x40 : not found.. Shouldn't it be written as cmd='i2cset','-y','0', '0x20','0x14','0x01'); subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)?

Comment: When I try it in the shell it says 'Error: write failed'( since there is no device to write or read into)

Comment: it's `' '.join(cmd)`, not `''.join(cmd)` (a space is needed inside of quotations)..

Comment: @NamitaRaju Actually I've deleted the one with `join()` as I thought it's just confusing. The `subprocess.call() ` should return the same error message as you get in your shell. I'd recommend to retry `subprocess.call('i2cset -y 0 0x20 0x14 0x01')` again (it's equivalent to the one in my answer) and confirm you'll see the same output as what you see in the shell.

Comment: I rectified my mistake and I get the same error as my shell.. Thank you for all the help :)