# Difference between whole string command and list of strings in popen

Tags: python, shell, command, popen

I found most of the programmers suggest use list of strings to represent the command in popen. However, in my own project, I found a whole string works in more cases.

For example, the following works

```
subprocess.Popen('pgrep -f "\./run"', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).wait()
```

while

```
subprocess.Popen(['pgrep', '-f', '"\./run"'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).wait()
```

does not.

May I know what's the difference between these two ways of implementation and why the second one does not work as expected?

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess). In this case your better version fails because your argument should be `'\./run'` and not `'"\./run"'`. I'd go so far as to say that you should never, ever use `shell=True`.

Comment: But if the command depends on some environment settings, I will need to use `shell=True`, right? @thatotherguy

Comment: Any command would inherit the same environment variables as a shell would, unless the environment is set up in the shell's init files. If you have a specific, good reason to require a shell, it would be better to explicitly invoke it like `['/bin/bash', '-c', 'some shell command', 'args...']` as this lets you choose the shell to depend on and more safely pass in data.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot! @thatotherguy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second should not have a `shell=True` parameter. Instead, it should be:
`subprocess.Popen(['pgrep', '-f', '"\./run"'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).wait()`.

The `shell` parameter sets whether or not to execute the command in a separate shell. That is, if a new shell should be spawned just to execute the command, which must be interpreted by the shell before it can be run.

When providing a list of strings, however, this does not spawn a second shell, and thus is (minimally) faster. It is also better to use for processing variable input, because it avoids string interpolation.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15109975/1730261

Comment: Passing a list with `shell=True` will not immediately fail on Windows, but is arguably wrong nevertheless. On Unix-like platforms, it will "mysteriously" lose the items after the first. Maybe see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess