# Python subprocess works different on Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

Inside a Flask app I try to run Python `subprocess` module. All worked on Ubuntu 12.04 with Python 2.7.8 and now I'm trying to check if the app works on Windows as well (Win7 x64, Python 2.7.12). My piece of code that **works** on Linux:

```
try:
    command = ["pgsql2shp -f %s -h %s -u %s -P %s %s main.%s" % (path, host, user, pword, db_name, region)] 

    work = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Above doesn't on Windows, returning `stderr` like "The filename directory name or volume syntax is incorrect".

But:

```
try:
    work = subprocess.Popen("pgsql2shp -f %s -h %s -u %s -P %s %s main.%s" % (path, host, user, pword, db_name, region), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Above **works** on Windows! What is the reason here? The error brought me to thinking that my `path` variable is incorrect, but it is as below:

```
path = 'D:/adam/files/test.shp'
print path # D:/adam/files/test.shp

path = os.normpath(path)
print path # D:\adam\files\test.shp
path # 'D:\\adam\\files\\test.shp'
```

If I run postgres' `pgsql2shp` from Windows cmd and just paste whatever combination of `\`, `\\` or `/` in string and the data I use here, it works good. Looks like `pgsql2sgp` converts the path to needed format itself. Then why it won't work through Python script and separate `command` variable?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109665/subprocess-call-using-string-vs-using-list

Comment: Thank you, that link helps me to deal with other problems I have with `subprocesses`, but to this question what actually helped me is a comment that is already deleted (was it yours, @cdarke ?) - the argument should be a list so, I just put `command` into `[ ]` and all is fine.

Comment: it was my comment, but I thought the other question answered it more fully.   Glad is now OK.

Comment: Never use an args list with `shell=True`, especially not on Windows. `subprocess.list2cmdline` doesn't have a clue about how to properly quote and escape a command line for cmd.exe and subsequent child processes.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. You said "especially not on Windows", however I tried `shell=False` on Ubuntu and couldn't make it work any way (with `command` being a list or a string and passed as `[command]` or `command`. Seems not to work for me on Ubuntu with `False`

Comment: A Unix novice may be in for a surprise when using an args list. What happens is the arguments are passed to the shell itself, e.g. try `subprocess.call(['echo $0 $1', 'spam', 'eggs'], shell=True)`.

Comment: yes, in my case, just as in your example, the shell must then be `True` in Unix. thank you!