# Python subprocess call to xpdf's pdftotext not working with encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, pdftotext

I am trying to run `pdftotext` using python `subprocess` module.

```
import subprocess

pdf = r"path\to\file.pdf"
txt = r"path\to\out.txt"
pdftotext = r"path\to\pdftotext.exe"

cmd = [pdftotext, pdf, txt, '-enc UTF-8']
response = subprocess.check_output(cmd, 
                shell=True,
                stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

**TB**

```
CalledProcessError: Command '['path\\to\\pdftotext.exe',
'path\\to\\file.pdf', 'path\\to\\out.txt', '-enc UTF-8']'
returned non-zero exit status 99
```

When I remove last argument '-enc UTF-8' from cmd, it works OK in python.

When I run `pdftotext pdf txt -enc UTF-8` in `cmd`, it works ok.

What I am missing?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you need `[pdftotext, pdf, txt, '-enc', 'UTF-8']`

Comment: I tried but it, works but encoding is not working. it give ANSI encoded file.

Comment: I see.... pass the command as a string?

Comment: I moved everything in single folder then `cmd = r"pdftotext file.pdf demo.txt -enc UTF-8"` worked perfectly. so the problem is with `cmd` formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess` has some complicated rules for handling commands. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):

> The shell argument (which defaults to False) specifies whether to use
>   the shell as the program to execute. If shell is True, it is
>   recommended to pass args as a string rather than as a sequence.

More details explained in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15109975/4909087).

So, as the docs explain, you should convert your command to a string:

```
cmd = r"""{} "{}" "{}" -enc UTF-8""".format('pdftotext', pdf, txt)
```

Now, call `subprocess` as:

```
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: I Tried `cmd = r"""{} "{}" "{}" -enc UTF-8""".format(pdftotext, pdf, txt)` as there were spaces in my path and the files are generated dynamically.