# User input in subprocess.call

Tags: python, subprocess, user-input, qiime

I am writing a program to automate some qiime2 commands. I want to incorporate user input.

So far, I have:

```
# Items to import
import subprocess
from sys import argv

#Variables
format=argv[1]

# Import sequences for Phred33 format
if format=='Phred33':
    cmnd = 'qiime tools import --type SampleData[PairedEndSequencesWithQuality] --input-path manifest.csv --output-path paired-end-demux.qza --source-format PairedEndFastqManifestPhred33'
    print('executing {}'.format(cmnd))
    res = subprocess.call(cmnd, shell=True)
    print('command terminated with status', res)

# Import sequences for Phred64 format
if format=='Phred64':
    cmnd = 'qiime tools import --type SampleData[PairedEndSequencesWithQuality] --input-path manifest.csv --output-path paired-end-demux.qza --source-format PairedEndFastqManifestPhred64'
    print('executing {}'.format(cmnd))
    res = subprocess.call(cmnd, shell=True)
    print('command terminated with status', res)
```

This works fine since there's only two possible user inputs, but I'd rather not have the if statements down  the line when there will be countless possible user inputs.

This would be better:

```
cmnd = 'qiime tools import --type SampleData[PairedEndSequencesWithQuality] --input-path manifest.csv --output-path paired-end-demux.qza --source-format PairedEndFastqManifest', format
```

But qiime2 gives me errors with this. Is there another way?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking how to insert `Phred33` or `Phred64` at the end of the string which is otherwise the same? You can use the `format` method for that (you are using it already!)

Comment: @mkrieger Thanks for commenting. Yes, that's what trying to do. I've never used subprocess before, so I don't understand what you mean by `format` method. I'm just using `format` here as a variable name. Could you clarify for me please?

Comment: You're using it in your `print`. It replaces the `{}` part of a string by what you supply as an argument.

Comment: @mkrieger1 oh wow, sorry I missed that! Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `shell=True` when the command you are executing is built from unsanitized user input. It can lead to the user being able to execute arbitrary commands, even if this is not wanted.

Also, pass the command as a list to `subprocess.call` to avoid issues with quoting.

```
cmnd = [
    'qiime', 'tools', 'import',
    '--type', 'SampleData[PairedEndSequencesWithQuality]',
    '--input-path', 'manifest.csv',
    '--output-path', 'paired-end-demux.qza',
    '--source-format', 'PairedEndFastq{}'.format(format)
]
print('executing {}'.format(' '.join(cmnd)))
res = subprocess.call(cmnd)
```

#### References, related questions

- [subprocess.call using string vs using list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109665/subprocess-call-using-string-vs-using-list)
- [Actual meaning of 'shell=True' in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!