# python variables as argument in subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am running below Python code & using `subprocess` to call one Python script. It is not able to substitute the value of `${ENVIRONMENT}`.

```
import sys
import subprocess

#ENVIRONMENT=sys.argv[1]
ENVIRONMENT='test'

url=subprocess.check_output("python env.py ${ENVIRONMENT}", shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use string formatting:

```
url = subprocess.check_output(
    "python env.py {ENVIRONMENT}".format(ENVIRONMENT=ENVIRONMENT), shell=True)
```

or pass your [command as a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109665/subprocess-call-using-string-vs-using-list):

```
url = subprocess.check_output(["python", "env.py", ENVIRONMENT])
```

Comment: Great—now can we tell people to either use environment variables (if there’s some reason for the shell to be aware of them) or (better) avoid the shell entirely?  Generating shell commands is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Well, it is probably a misnomer. If you look at the example it is just a Python variable and not an O/S environment variable. Even the commented out line hints that it's a command line argument.

Comment: I’m saying it’s reasonable to *set* it as an environment variable for use in subprocesses (as for the shell-command syntax in the question), or to use it as an argument to them, but not (usually) to use it as a substring of a shell command.