# How do you "launch" a Windows protocol from Python?

Tags: python-3.x, windows

We have a python script that needs to trigger the open of the Microsoft Store. We believe that the easiest way to do that is to use the [ms-windows-store://](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-store-app) protocol.

We're currently doing that like this

```
import subprocess
ret = subprocess.call(["start", "ms-windows-store://pdp/?ProductId=9WZDNCRFHVJL"], shell=True)
```

Is that the recommended way to do this? I'm not sure if using `start` is correct here, or if there's something better?

Comment: `subprocess` can be used to run commands via Python. I  your case if `start windows-store://pdp/?ProductId=9WZDNCRFHVJL` is a correct command, it is correct. For detailed info on parameters of subprocess call, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15109975/4636715

Comment: Thank you! That’s exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `os.startfile("ms-windows-store://pdp/?ProductId=9WZDNCRFHVJL")`. This calls WINAPI `ShellExecuteW` directly. If you use subprocess, you have the expense of starting a child process. Plus CMD's `start` command will first search `PATH` to find a file that it can execute. Presuming nothing is found (and nothing likely will be, given this name), it hands the request off to `ShellExecuteExW` to let the OS shell handle it.