# Call a external python script

Tags: python, algorithm, subprocess, pipeline

what's wrong with the code below:

```
command_assembly = f'{self.INPUT_ASSEMBLY_SRC}{self.file} ' \
    f'{self.ASSEMBLER} {self.ONLY_ASSEMBLY} {self.MIN_PARAMS} ' \
    f'{self.CUT_OFF} {cutoff} '\
    f'-o out'

result = subprocess.run([self.APP_ASSEMBLY, command_assembly], capture_output=True, text=True)`
```

In my tests, the run method seems to only capture one parameter and not the entire string that contains multiple parameters. Remembering that running in the terminal everything works perfectly with the string above.

Comment: If you want to use a command string that works in a shell, you need a call like this: `subprocess.run("program -a -b -o out", shell=True)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code was as follows:

```
command_assembly = f'{a} {b} {c}'
result = subprocess.run([self.APP_ASSEMBLY, command_assembly], capture_output=True, text=True)`
```

You would be calling `self.APP_ASSEMBLY` with only one argument, which would be the values of `a`, `b` and `c` separated by spaces.

This is different from what you almost certainly want, 3 arguments, which would be accomplished like this:

```
command_assembly = [f'{a}', f'{b}', f'{c}']
result = subprocess.run([self.APP_ASSEMBLY, ...command_assembly], capture_output=True, text=True)`
```

The code you provided, once corrected, would then look like this:

```
command_assembly = [f'{self.INPUT_ASSEMBLY_SRC}{self.file}',
    f'{self.ASSEMBLER}', f'{self.ONLY_ASSEMBLY}', f'{self.MIN_PARAMS}',
    f'{self.CUT_OFF}', f'{cutoff}',
    '-o', 'out']

result = subprocess.run([self.APP_ASSEMBLY, *command_assembly], capture_output=True, text=True)`
```

Further explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15109975/1460016).

Comment: The above code didn't work, the liginity example was more useful, serving what I wanted.

Comment: "didn't work" how, exactly?

Comment: I have corrected a mixup in syntax in the answer

Comment: Now it works! Great. The * in command_assembly is like *args? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes! You could also have included APP_ASSEMBLY in the first line, of course. I got JS and Python's syntaxes mixed up